# Getting a 'The data types nvarchar(max) and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator.'

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x

I am trying to populate a table with data and am using Django's get_or_create method. Whenever I do this it will enter records into the database but at a certain record it will throw the above error. My queryset function is

```
r, created = Response.objects.get_or_create(
    auth_user=auth_user,
    name=surv_name,
    organization=org_id,
    category=category,
    question=question,
    present_order=present_order,
    reference=reference,
    quest_id=quest_id,
    survey_id=survey_id
)
```

My response table is

```
class Response(models.Model):
    auth_user = models.ForeignKey('AuthUser')
    survey = models.ForeignKey('Survey')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization')
    tf_question_key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    quest_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    present_order = models.IntegerField()
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    remediation = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True, null=True)
    dt_started = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DT_Started',
        auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dt_completed = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DT_COMPLETED',
        auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'response'
```

and the traceback where the error is located is

```
organization  <Organization: Individual Offices>
r  <Response: Response object>
user_id  2
question  ('Does your written policy include the follow-up process for significant outstanding checks, including, but not limited to, checks to recording clerk, checks to tax collector, hazard insurance checks, underwriter checks or checks for mortgage payoffs and any other high risk items? ( 2.03 k )')
present_order  21
survey_id  1
reference  '2.03 (k)'
quest_id  27
created  True
category  'Pillar II'
surv_name  'Compliance Benchmark'
org_id  1
auth_user  <AuthUser: AuthUser object>
```

I can add records to the table by using

```
r = Response(
    auth_user=auth_user,
    name=surv_name,
    organization=organization,
    category=category,
    question=question,
    present_order=present_order,
    reference=reference,
    quest_id=quest_id,
    survey_id=survey_id
)
r.save()
```

but I need to use the get_or_create method to avoid duplicating records. I am not sure why I can add records with the .save() method but not with get_or_create and also why with get_or_create it will add records up to a certain one and then fail. The only thing that is changing is the question, quest_id, present_order, and reference.

I am using python 3.4, django 1.8.4 and SQL Server 2014

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is because the ntext datatype cannot be compared using equality. That datatype has been deprecated in favor of nvarchar(max) since 2005. You should consider updating your datatype.

Comment: I have checked in SQL server and all of my datatypes are nvarchar, int or datetime. Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and turned on logging on sql server to see what was occurring. It looks like long text fields are being converted to ntext. This is then being compared to the nvarchar field causing the error.

The error is occurring during the SELECT within the get_or_create function. Instead of using get_or_create, query for your model with startswith. Using startswith performs a LIKE check which will work. I also added a length check on the field to ensure the fields will match instead of finding other rows with the same starting value.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.models.functions import Length

attrs = {
    auth_user=auth_user,
    name=surv_name,
    organization=org_id,
    category=category,
    present_order=present_order,
    reference=reference,
    quest_id=quest_id,
    survey_id=survey_id,
}

try:
    r = Response.objects.annotate(
        text_len=Length('question')
    ).get(
        text_len__exact=len(question),
        question__startswith=question,
        **attrs
    )
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    r = Response.objects.create(
        question=question,
        **attrs
    )
```