# Resolving variables are incompatible in the equal to operator error in SQL

Tags: python, django, sql-server-2012

I am getting the following error in django `model.objects.get_or_create`.

```
SQLServer [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The data types nvarchar(max) and ntext
are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

The column django is complaining about `NVARCHAR(MAX)` with null allowed in SQLServer.

The Django model element is defined as `TextField(null=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Sql-Server is converting the Django TextField to nText and trying to compare to nVarChar like this post answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961820/8648964

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35021870)